# Design Critique/Feedback Websites

Tags: resource-recommendations, critique

After quite a lot of searching, I haven't really find that many websites focused on design critique, where you could just upload your work and get some responses.

One of the biggest sites oriented on *artsy* people is probably [DeviantArt](http://deviantart.com), which is really great, but it is nearly impossible (at least for me) to get some relevant critique on newly added work.

**The problem that I see with sites like DA is that they don't *reward* the people who comment/rate/critique.**

On StackExchange we have the Karma system, as people get little points when they post a good answer, which greatly enhances the community to be active.

**Is there any such a site for designers, where it doesn't take milion years to get a response for newly uploaded stuff?** The only one I was able to find is **[Dribbble](http://dribbble.com)**, which however is a invite-only service.

Comment: I wanna know how to get invited to dribbble if you can't show anything to prove you should be on dribbble...

Answer (score 3):

This question on Meta offers up a good list of critique websites: [Meta: Asking community to critique work](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/asking-community-to-critique-work/30#30)

Comment: and as per the first answer to that question, this site is also an option for critique if you follow with the conditions Robert outlined. for example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/976/making-an-effective-menu

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the kind of work you do. For typesetting and branding, for example, the [typophile](http://www.typophile.com) forums are your best bet.

I can't post comments yet, but can you elaborate what kind of work you do?

Comment: I'm doing mostly web design.

Comment: Then go for typophile for graphic design and typography issues, and check out [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=90) and [this](http://forums.devshed.com/website-critiques-89/). I think you'll generally find more technical advice than individual critique, but if you ask specific questions (and not "how do you like this site?") you may actually get some good advice.