# Self taught graphic designer Is there a GPS for steps in learning?

Tags: logo, education

The funny thing is it seems I have more clients then skills to match it. When I say that, what I mean is, I do logos and flyers even help with placement on sites like wixs and word press for web.

Now my niche is that I work with musicians. I actually was asked to do a logo and business card for the keyboard player for Alicia Keys. I don't say that to tute my own horn I say that because, I might have the creative eye sight and brainstorm thought process, but I am sure (whether the client notices or not ) I lack detailed technique.

I use adobe suites (watching another beginner video on illustrator is so not helping). Is there a place or (mentor) that can point me to a starting path?

I seem to jump from this to that and have myself caught in learning 10 different things that I spend more time on a catch up then getting work done.

I would like to add that, even though this question resembles what beginner designers should do , but the fact is I am not a beginner I am in a limbo unsure of the direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pick up applications I recommend https://www.vtc.com/ or https://www.lynda.com -- Once you pay for something, you tend to be more focused. If you are hesitant to pay for training.. then you may need to ask yourself how truly vested are you in becoming a proficient professional. You **can't** learn everything via free online tutorials.

In addition, many of the topics covered in *actual* training videos will be hard to find as "free videos" on the web. Free web tutorials are created based on things that have a "wow" factor and are used as click bait.. not educational sources. Even many of Adobe's own video fall into a "click bait" category.

If you have more work than you can handle, *raise your prices*. That's how everyone else handles it. You may be getting too much work because you're priced so low it's a no-brainer for many to hire you.

As for a "path" or "GPS" - no there's none. It's all individualized. You have to follow what you want or need to learn. No one can determine that for you. I would merely suggest you pick *one thing* and learn *that* to your satisfaction before moving on to something else. And that includes projects.. if you are learning Illustrator but also *want* to learn After Effects.. don't take on After Effects projects until you have a handle on Illustrator.

Be systematic in your approach to learning. It will not only assist in keeping things clear in your mind, but will also make learning subsequent applications/technologies easier.

For more aesthetic areas.. you may try these questions:

[Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

[Suggestion on introductory books about graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29553/suggestion-on-introductory-books-about-graphic-design)

[Best resources/way/curriculum to learn Graphic Design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74521/best-resources-way-curriculum-to-learn-graphic-design)

[How to become really good in graphic design from being average?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18822/how-to-become-really-good-in-graphic-design-from-being-average)

[How do I learn to be creative?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative)

Comment: I would add that you should check with your local library and see if they offer any online training... I get access to all of Lynda.com (for Free) just by having a library card.

Comment: Good point @GoofyMonkey -- if you still *have* a Library it's worth looking into.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey and Metis I have no problem in paying for training. I think its just that, there is so much  info you get lost in what is, or where the info is that is going to benefit you and what is more fluff. On top of I don't want to subscribe to 5 different sites that pretty much do or have the same videos. I wasn't to sure about Lynda, but if that's a good one maybe I will try my hand on that one

Comment: It's a pretty decent site. I've used it a lot in the past. I was just pointing out a program that I was only made aware of recently.

Answer (score 3):

You need to figure out what exactly it is that you need to learn first. You already have a skillset and like you said, it would be pointless to follow another beginner tutorial.

Take a moment to really criticise your work. Compare it to work you see from artists you like (Look on Behance, Dribbble etc). Once you've made a list of points you need to work on, you can start looking for specific tutorials or ask questions here. I actually learned most of my things by replicating work I liked. Obviously you should not use this work for commercial purpose but recreating a certain asset or style from scratch can really teach you a lot.

On this SE you can let other people criticise your work as well, but make sure you read the guidelines on this before you ask.